# Lib angular file upload with field data object json

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I'm using lib `angular-file-upload`.

How do I add the date field of `$http` request on request below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload']);

app.controller('Aula21Controller', function($scope, FileUploader){

    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url : 'http://localhost:8080/work/v1/chats',
        alias: 'message-body',
        headers: {'X-Client-Instance': '1.221@0000010000083359', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata'},    
    });
```

In my request needs to send a json object (date field) with the items below:

```
json object - data 

{
    "receiver":"", 
    "localAddress":"", // ip 
    "attachment":"", // name file
    "content":"" // content message
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using this lib: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/, you can pass additional data using the `formData` property